# Seek for good methods of computing the Krull dimension of a module?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hi, everyone. Recently I am interested in computing the Krull dimensions of modules without  using any software. However, it is not an easy job for me to do so only by its definition. Therefore, I hope that someone could give me some suggestions. Let $R$ be a commutative ring, the Krull dimension of an $R$-module $M$, denoted by $dimM$, is defined by $dimM=dimSupp(M)$. The following two examples have confused me for a long time.
Ex. 1 Let $R=k[[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]]$, let $M=R/(x_1)\cap (x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Then $dimM=4$.

Ex. 2 Let $S=K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]$, $I_1=(x_1,x_2,x_3^4,x_6)$, $I_2=(x_2,x_3^3,x_5)$,
$I_3=(x_3^2,x_4)$, set $m=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ and $R=S_m$, $J=I_1\cap I_2\cap I_3\cap (x_3)$. Let $M=R/JR$. Then $dimM=5$.

Comment: Hint: Dimension of $R/(I\cap J)$ is the maximal of dimensions of $R/I, R/J$ (geometrically, union of 2 components). 

Comment: @Hailong Dao: Your hint is useful, thank you!